# C# проблема с вытаскиванием данных из таблицы SQL

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, form

пишу курсовую  на C# windows Form с базой SQL. Задача состоит в том что бы сделать обучающие приложение, с авторизацией и регистрацией прооблем не возникло, возникли проблемы с выводом теста из бд, суть в том что мне нужно поочередно брать из таблицы текст, в таблице столбцы ID и TEXT

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В чём проблема `SELECT` в таблицу, а потом из неё вытаскивать?

Comment: Что используете для работы с БД: ADO.NET, микро-ОРМ наподобие Dapper или большую ОРМ наподобие Entity Framework Core?

Comment: С чем у вас _конкретная_ проблема? Не получается подключиться к БД, не получается написать SQL-запрос (или LINQ-запрос), не получается спроектировать GUI? Или что-то ещё?